# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to fetch the data in three tables by using their `version` columns.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].tblCALPLA(ACCOUNT,DATASRC,VERSION)

SELECT ACCOUNT,DATASRC,VERSION FROM [dbo].TBLFACT
WHERE VERSION=(SELECT ID FROM [dbo].VERSION)

UNION

SELECT ACCOUNT,DATASRC,VERSION FROM [dbo].TBLFACT1
WHERE VERSION=(SELECT ID FROM [dbo].VERSION)

UNION

SELECT ACCOUNT,DATASRC,VERSION FROM [dbo].TBLFACT2
WHERE VERSION=(SELECT ID FROM [dbo].VERSION)
```

Comment: There are several rows in `[dbo].VERSION`; you either need to filter out unwanted ones in query or delete them beforehand (table name `Version` suggests a singleton).

Answer (score 1):

In all your WHERE conditions, instead of

```
WHERE Version = (SELECT ID ...)
```

make use of

```
WHERE Version IN (SELECT ID...)
```